# Validation rule not working on default value in form

Tags: database, validation, ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2013

I have the validation rule "Is Not Null" on two of my fields in a form that is used to enter records into a table. My form asks for an ID, a forename, a surname and a date of birth, and the rule is in the forename and surname fields.

The validation rule works if something is typed in and then deleted, but if the user leaves either of these fields blank, enters the date and then clicks "Add Record", they can add a record to the table while leaving both the forename and surname fields empty despite the validation rule. The "Is Not Null" validation rule seems pointless if you can't validate a field's default value.

Answer (score 3):

A validation rule in a form field runs only when the data in this field is **changed**. So in your case it never runs.

If your data is in Access tables, you should set `Required = Yes` and `AllowZeroLength = No` in the table design for these fields. This will prevent saving a record with empty fields.

Alternatively, for more complex checks, the `Form.BeforeUpdate` event can be used.

Comment: Is there any way to have a presence check in a form field then?

Comment: Only with VBA, by setting `Cancel = True` in the `Form.BeforeUpdate` event.

Comment: Is that in Microsoft Access

Comment: Huh. Yes, of course. :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822421.aspx